# Solution set for two families of circles

Tags: geometry, elementary-set-theory, inequality, circles

If $X$ is the solution set of 
$$x^2+y^2-4x-2y+k=0 \\ 12x-5y+4=0$$

and $Y$ is the solution set of $$x^2+y^2-4x-2y+k=0 \\ 4x-3y+12=0$$
and the number of elements in $X \cup Y$ is 3,then find all possible values of $k$.

I tried writing the family of circles corresponding to the given circles and lines. Now to get real circles the radius must be real. Using these conditions I got some inequalities for $k$ but couldn't deduce the correct answer from them. Can anyone explain how this question could be done?

Comment: Rearrange $12x-5y+4=0$ for $y$, then plug this into $x^2+y^2-4x-2y+k=0$, then solve for $x$ as a quadratic equation (in terms of $k$). Do the same for the other set of equations, and compare the two solution sets with the given condition.

Comment: Are you sure there are 3 common points. It is intersection of a line and circle which can be at atmost 2 points.

Comment: Something is incorrect in your question because if $X$ and $Y$ share three points, then that would mean that the two straight lines have three points in common. This is impossible unless the lines are identical, which they are not.

Comment: As currently stated, both X and Y have at most two elements each, so it's impossible for their intersection to have three elements. Either the problem is impossible, or there has some misstatement, such as that the *union* of X and Y has 3 elements.

Comment: Sorry for the typo.  The question is that the number of elements in $X\cup Y$ is 3 then find all possible values of $k$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $|X \cup Y|=3$, this means there are two scenarios:

1. Circle passes through the intersection point $B(3,8)$ of the two lines and then intersects each line at one additional point. OR
2. Circle intersects one line ($12x-5y=-4$) at two points and is tangent to the other line ($4x-3y=-12$).

**Case 1** The point of intersection $B$ is $(3,8)$ and the given circle is
$$(x-2)^2+(y-1)^2=5-k \qquad \text{with center } A(2,1)$$
Let $r$ be the radius of the circle, then $r^2=5-k$ and $r=\text{dist}(A,B)=\sqrt{(3-2)^2+(8-1)^2}=5\sqrt{2}$. Thus $k=-45$.

**Case 2** The distance of the center $A(2,1)$ from the line $4x-3y=-12$ will be the radius. This gives you the other value of $k=\frac{8}{5}$.

[image]

Comment: According to your answer we would get only one value of k.  But the answer to this question is that there are 2 values of k

Comment: As the picture you posted you showed 2 circles with different centres. But in the question the centres of the circles are same and what varies is the radius

Comment: @Greninja You are right. I made an error with picture.

Comment: Would please post your total solution so I understand what you actually mean to say.

Comment: @Greninja I have posted the entire solution. Hopefully this will help.

Comment: +1 I was going to post my own answer but you beat me to it. Geometry ftw.

Comment: @Anurag A.  Thank you very much.